# How can I construct a java.security.PublicKey object from a base64 encoded string?

Tags: java, security, rsa

I have a bse64encoded string Public key from external source (Android Store) and I need to use it to verify signed content. How can I convert the string into an instance of the java.security.PublicKey interface. I am on Java 6 if that makes a difference.

The key is (probably) generated using standard java lib and not bouncy castle (its from a remote team so I am not sure). Their sample code says to use Security.generatePublicKey(base64EncodedPublicKey); but the Security object in standard java has no such method.

Comment: What are you using to create your key, the standard java libary, BouncyCastle or something else?

Comment: Standard java very probably but its a remote team so I am not sure

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok for grins ... try this

- base64 decode the key data to get a byte array (byte[])
- Create a new X509EncodedKeySpec using the byte array
- Get an instance of KeyFactory using KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA") assuming RSA here
- call the method generatePublic(KeySpec) with the X509EncodedKeySpec
- Result /should/ be a public key for your usage.

Comment: Had same issue, tried this and got this exception `java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format`

Comment: I get the same exception. I tried removineding the "BEGIN and END CERTIFICATE" and still get the same error.

Comment: As this solved for the requestor's situation, please ask a new question on stackoverflow and provide link here. Please provide code examples of what you are doing and utilize an example certificate e.g. http://fm4dd.com/openssl/source/PEM/certs/2048b-rsa-example-cert.pem. Ideally, sign up for a github account and provide a link to the repository containing your exemplar code and test certificate.

Answer (score 78):

Code for the above answer

```
public static PublicKey getKey(String key){
    try{
        byte[] byteKey = Base64.decode(key.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        return kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I was using a similar piece of code, but this is better ;)
Also if working on android you could use:
byte[] byteKey = Base64.decode(key.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: @Hooli: It's "android.util.Base64". Anyway, the value of DEFAULT is 0.

Comment: Obviously, you can you Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytes) method from java.util.

Comment: I modified the first line like this to make it work in Java 8 `byte[] byteKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(key.getBytes());`

Answer (score 4):

Try this....

```
PublicKey getPublicKey(byte[] encodedKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec encodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
    return factory.generatePublic(encodedKeySpec);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
try {
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(this.stringValue("n")));
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(this.stringValue("e")));
    return kf.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent));
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException var4) {
    throw new InvalidPublicKeyException("Invalid public key", var4);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException var5) {
    throw new InvalidPublicKeyException("Invalid algorithm to generate key", var5);
}
```

Comment: although not what the question asked, this works well if you have the JWK or have the PEM to convert to JWK online

Answer (score 0):

Using spongy castle

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws Exception {
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey pkcs1PublicKey
            = org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey.getInstance(decodeB64(key));
    RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec
            = new RSAPublicKeySpec(pkcs1PublicKey.getModulus(), pkcs1PublicKey.getPublicExponent());
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    return publicKey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this solution:

add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.70</version>
</dependency>
```

and use this method:

```
private Key parsePublicKey(String publicKey) throws IOException {
    try (StringReader sr = new StringReader(publicKey)) {
        PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(sr);
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter();
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(parser.readObject());
        return converter.getPublicKey(publicKeyInfo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle me
    }
}
```