# InvalidKeySpecException data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, token

I get an access token on Azure Portal free subscription, the header is:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "7_Zuf1tvkwLxYaHS3q6lUjUYIGw",
  "kid": "7_Zuf1tvkwLxYaHS3q6lUjUYIGw"
}
```

so I get the x5c from [here](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys), and put

-----Begin Certificate-----
MIIDBTCCAe......cNpO9oReBUsX
-----End Certificate-----

```
    ze7xq1zGljQihJgcNpO9oReBUsX
```

in https://jwt.io/, Signature is Verified.

But when I try to verify the signature with jjwt and jose4j with JDK1.8, following steps in [this refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900643/how-can-i-construct-a-java-security-publickey-object-from-a-base64-encoded-strin), I get below exception on the line

> *PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);*

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:204)
at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:352)
at com.ipscape.api.v1_0.external.other.JwtExample.decodeJwt(JwtExample.java:41)
at com.ipscape.api.v1_0.external.other.JwtExample.main(JwtExample.java:72)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:396)
at java.base/sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:401)
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:86)
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:297)
at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:200)
```

The codes using jose4j:

```
        String publicKeyPEM =
        "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";

    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM.getBytes()));
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

    JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
        .setRequireExpirationTime()
        .setVerificationKey(publicKey)
        .build();
```

Comment: You can take a look at https://community.auth0.com/t/problem-validating-jwt-with-x509-cert-pubkey-from-jwks/9705

Answer (score 13):

[**x5c is a (X.509) certificate, not a public key.**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.6) Actually it is an a array of certs forming a chain if necessary, although this example is a single selfsigned cert. The PEM header and trailer lines for a cert should say 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE' and 'END CERTIFICATE' in all-caps, and the base64 should have linebreaks added, unlike the JWT format which is base64 but is *NOT* PEM.

To read a cert use [`java.security.cert.CertificateFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html). (This can also handle a chain, as either just a sequence of certs which it calls PkiPath, or a (trivial) PKCS7 message which is standard and usually called p7b or p7c.) Either give it the *correct* PEM format, or the correct binary/DER format; the latter is easier because it is just base64-decoding the JWT x5c format (as you are now doing, before you put it in a keyspec which is wrong, but [`java.util.Base64.Decoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html) doesn't require the base64 in bytes, it can take a `String`). If you only need the pubkey, you can then get it from the cert. Do something like:

```
String certb64 = "...";
byte[] certder = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certb64);
InputStream certstream = new ByteArrayInputStream (certder);
Certificate cert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(certstream);
PublicKey key = cert.getPublicKey();
```

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085, I add below codes after getting PublicKey, 
`        Claims body = null;
        JwtParser jwtParser = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key.getEncoded());
        Jws<Claims> claimsJws=jwtParser.parseClaimsJws(token);
        body =claimsJws.getBody();`  

Then it get 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key bytes can only be specified for HMAC signatures. Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.
 at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541)
`

Comment: which is io/jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.9.0/jjwt-0.9.0-sources.jar!/io/jsonwebtoken/impl/DefaultJwtParser.java
                    Assert.isTrue(algorithm.isHmac(),
                                  "Key bytes can only be specified for HMAC signatures. Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.");

but the algorithm="RS256", not HMAC. Is anything wrong?

Comment: @Henryips I was going to say please put changes to your Q in your Q, because Stack policy is that comments can be deleted any time and especially code is unreadable -- but as you already found an answer probably no one needs to read your Q.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
        JwtConsumer jwtConsumer = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
        .setRequireExpirationTime()
        .setExpectedAudience("https://example.com/")
        .setVerificationKey(publicKey)
        .build();

    JwtClaims jwtDecoded = null;
    jwtDecoded = jwtConsumer.processToClaims(token);

    Map<String, Object> jwtClaims = jwtDecoded.getClaimsMap();
    String iss = (String) jwtClaims.get("iss");
```