# Verifying a signature signed in javascript inside a Kotlin application

Tags: kotlin, cryptojs

I have a code that signs a payload in Javascript and I want to verify the Signaure on the same inside another application written in Kotlin. I am using the 'secp256k' library .I can sign it on the js side but verification fails on Kotlin side

Comment: Hi Pranav, it would help us solve your issue a bit more if you provide some code, and maybe an error you run into. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikPragt:  I am using the following js library to sign https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsontokens and the following java library to verify
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900643/how-can-i-construct-a-java-security-publickey-object-from-a-base64-encoded-strin     The error I am seeing is invalid key format

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using jrassign library . the issue is due to the fact that keys are encoded differently in java and javascript. java follows ASN 1 standard while there appears to be no fixed standard in javascript