# Creating a DSA PublicKey in Java from a PEM string

Tags: java, cryptography, dsa

Having created a DSA keypair using

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

And then converting the public key part into pem format using

```
openssl dsa -in mytestkey -pubout
```

I then try to construct a PublicKey using the following:

```
            private static final String PUBLIC_KEY_PEM =
            "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n" +
                    "MIIBtzCCASsGByqGSM44BAEwggEeAoGBAJLJRIrDdiwbB6iWZTWowprJB8QfbLK7\n" +
                    "8OUCoj6Ot5nfEL5VDPcc0v1rCGQxmL+nijPQsxA0LTucBySlkj6AvGIdND6yY7Qx\n" +
                    "OZYeP6UErByzVhmDNG2MIhK7SL36O3uutOJKr86aTiDxP8/zSUO8JPZHqtr2K2Cm\n" +
                    "lY6LQpocGnZ/AhUAmA/eq9AcGaNAqbT6ebB3IE3qWKkCgYAuh3zCz9aTPJ8+D9to\n" +
                    "6xjjE6SEqKM4EDaA8kpV/363ad8kZRLRmtxTGDpIKV/k4ebb94+4o6VEFJKTUH7t\n" +
                    "7c5uj8Hnr+8scctFE85nXprpK/CmxvWIZRl0AWjz1/8hoaUX3ZcLz9QbOLk1deSS\n" +
                    "BksFgKZQgoaNVY3PPq0pjNfdCAOBhQACgYEAkDATEoqoCXMOy/LK+TOBqXWu3Tex\n" +
                    "kkBMTJxYHyhXqmBLvvkiwBX1wz0i58Zg0Qde4euHXrYwYzufBXeMZ9p3Wku7VIwD\n" +
                    "4PfefBAZhzCJ+Dh937T/2dI/PqNIObZb28I7TXD/SQfwXurKDnGdl16LHmMcZ7bS\n" +
                    "d6AFgUd73b+Obh8=\n" +
                    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
                    KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(PUBLIC_KEY_PEM.getBytes()));
```

However I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification: invalid key format
at sun.security.provider.DSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(DSAKeyFactory.java:119)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
at com.dave.testing.RandomTesting.generatePublicKey2(RandomTesting.java:60)
```

Why is my code not correct?

Comment: Try adding `Base64.decode(PUBLIC_KEY_PEM.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);` . It should work.

Comment: Also, you can find the proper answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900643/how-can-i-construct-a-java-security-publickey-object-from-a-base64-encoded-strin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key is currently encoded using base64. In order to read it using a `X509EncodedKeySpec` you need to decode it. You can use any Base64 decoder for this, I used the one provided by `BouncyCastle` for now.
For this to work you need to strip it from the non-Base64 parts (the `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` lines respectively).

The following code snippet works using `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64`:

```
final String PUBLIC_KEY_PEM = "MIIBtzCCASsGByqGSM44BAEwggEeAoGBAJLJRIrDdiwbB6iWZTWowprJB8QfbLK7\n"
                                        + "8OUCoj6Ot5nfEL5VDPcc0v1rCGQxmL+nijPQsxA0LTucBySlkj6AvGIdND6yY7Qx\n"
                                        + "OZYeP6UErByzVhmDNG2MIhK7SL36O3uutOJKr86aTiDxP8/zSUO8JPZHqtr2K2Cm\n"
                                        + "lY6LQpocGnZ/AhUAmA/eq9AcGaNAqbT6ebB3IE3qWKkCgYAuh3zCz9aTPJ8+D9to\n"
                                        + "6xjjE6SEqKM4EDaA8kpV/363ad8kZRLRmtxTGDpIKV/k4ebb94+4o6VEFJKTUH7t\n"
                                        + "7c5uj8Hnr+8scctFE85nXprpK/CmxvWIZRl0AWjz1/8hoaUX3ZcLz9QbOLk1deSS\n"
                                        + "BksFgKZQgoaNVY3PPq0pjNfdCAOBhQACgYEAkDATEoqoCXMOy/LK+TOBqXWu3Tex\n"
                                        + "kkBMTJxYHyhXqmBLvvkiwBX1wz0i58Zg0Qde4euHXrYwYzufBXeMZ9p3Wku7VIwD\n"
                                        + "4PfefBAZhzCJ+Dh937T/2dI/PqNIObZb28I7TXD/SQfwXurKDnGdl16LHmMcZ7bS\n"
                                        + "d6AFgUd73b+Obh8=\n";
KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(PUBLIC_KEY_PEM)));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public static DSAPublicKey getPublicKeyFromString(String key) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String publicKeyPEM = key;
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
        publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
        byte[] encoded = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyPEM);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
        DSAPublicKey pubKey = (DSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));
        return pubKey;
    }
```

@Ben already answered above ;)