# JWT validation is failing : Key bytes cannot be specified for RSA signatures. Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance

Tags: java, jwt

I am trying to decode and verify *JWT* token in my service using the following code:

```java
String  jwtSecret= "my_key";
Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
        .setSigningKey(jwtSecret)
        .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
return claims;
```

The above code does not work and throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key bytes cannot be specified for RSA signatures.  Please specify a PublicKey or PrivateKey instance.
```

I have tried creating Public key also but it didn't work.
Can anyone state what I am missing?

Comment: How does your `jwt` token was issued?

Comment: Token is issued by other service which validates user generates the token.

Comment: You mean the token is beared through another service. But who's the Authorisation Server that issued the token initially?

Comment: yes. It is through another service. Actually my service is a handling websockets so at time of handshake I am getting token in path param and trying to validate token

Comment: From where do the other the service gets the token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key I was using was not correct. 
I came to know when I tried generating the token with the key I was using and decoded with my same above code and same key , it worked. 
So I checked with the team which was handling the JWT token generation I found key was different.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are JJWT for trying to decode the JWT. Where are you getting the public key from?

Instead of passing in the public key as a string, you should build a `PublicKey` first, then pass that in. If you have access to the exponent and modulus of the key:

```
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(key.getN()));

BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(key.getE()));

RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
return factory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
```

If you don't, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900643/how-can-i-construct-a-java-security-publickey-object-from-a-base64-encoded-strin) explains how you can build it from a string, but you have ensure that the string is formatted correctly.

In case you are interested, here is a more [detailed post that I wrote](https://sgonzal.com/2020/04/06/jwt-validation.html) on how to validate and parse a JWT signed by an Authorization server using JJWT.