# JCE: Store a private-key only without cert-chain

Tags: java, keystore, jce

With Java and JCE - I have to create a keypair, store it in a keystore and create a certificate-request.

As far I see I can only store a private-key with a certificate-chain.
But I do not have the certificate yes - but I need to store the key inside the keystore.

How to do that?
Is it possible that I can store a private key without a cert-chain or have an empty cert-chain?

```
KeyPair kp = ...
Keystore ks = ...
 
PrivateKeyEntry e = new PrivateKeyEntry (kp.getPrivate (), null);  // null does not work for cert-chain -> null  exception
ks.setEntry (id, e, pp);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188651/can-i-store-rsa-public-key-without-certificate-to-my-existing-jks-file

Comment: Don’t do this with code. Use the `keytool`.